# Should I remove install.php and install-helper.php?

Tags: security, installation

Is keeping `wp-admin/install.php` and `wp-admin/install-helper.php` a security leak on the newer versions of wordpress? By default file permission on those files are 644.

If there is any leak, what kind of please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there is no security risk. Both files do sanity checks before anything happens.

If WordPress is already installed:

- `install-helper.php` returns just a blank page.
- `install.php` says WordPress is installed and you should log in:
  [image]

You can forbid access to both files with a simple rule in your .htaccess above the permalink rules:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent wp-admin/install(-helper)?\.php /
```

This will redirect all requests to these files to the home page.

Answer (score -1):

```
# nginx configuration

location ~ wp-admin/install(-helper)?\.php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ / redirect;
}
```