# Wordpress installer attack

Tags: hacked

I'm facing a repeated attack on my wordpress.

The bots are attempting to force wordpress into installation mode, despite 503'ing requests for `install` globally and having heavily locked down security with `limited login attempts`, the `OSE firewall` and `Better WP Security`  they still appear to be able to force the site into installation mode which then generates a redirect loop.

Any ideas and help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the .htaccess rule I provided in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96620/should-i-remove-install-php-and-install-helper-php/96632#96632)? See also [Increase of failed login attempts, brute force attacks?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/95576/73)

Comment: I've given it a go - however the site is currently stuck in a redirect loop that I can't seem to break out of.

Comment: Try using `Wordfence`. It has a better firewall than `Better WP Security` in my opinion.